# Detect RSS feed update using php

Tags: php

I can get from the headers if there is an update on an rss feed but how do I compare two time stamps

`Last-Modified: Tue, 28 May 2013 09:31:30 GMT`

with

Last-Modified: Tue, 28 May 2013 11:31:30 GMT

Comment: `Last-Modified` usually doesn't go backwards, so you can just test for string equality: `"Tue, 28 May 2013 09:31:30 GMT" === "Tue, 28 May 2013 11:31:30 GMT"`.

Comment: [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Comment: And why the -ve on the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$time1 =  strtotime('Tue, 28 May 2013 09:31:30 GMT');
$time2 =  strtotime('Tue, 28 May 2013 11:31:30 GMT');
echo $timediff = abs($time2 -$time1);
```

Codepad Link - http://codepad.org/BA51mjlw

Answer (score 2):

`Last-Modified` usually doesn't go backwards, so you can just test for string equality:

```
"Tue, 28 May 2013 09:31:30 GMT" === "Tue, 28 May 2013 11:31:30 GMT"
```

If you really want to compare the dates, you can do this:

```
date_create("Tue, 28 May 2013 09:31:30 GMT") < date_create("Tue, 28 May 2013 11:31:30 GMT")
```